# control structures switch case C#

Tags: c#

Подскажите как правильно сравнить  2 переменные?

```
z = x-y;
switch (z)
{
case z < 0:
    F = Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y) * Math.Cos(y);
    break;
case z == 0:
    F = Math.Log(x);
    break;
case z > 0:
    F = Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y);
    break;
 }
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement

Comment: читал этот ресурс, но вылезает ошибка : error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<'

Comment: Версия компилятора?

Comment: Какая версия дотнета у вас?

Comment: пишу на быструю руку в песочнице, поэтому точно не скажу, а какая  версия нужна?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для .NET 5 с минимальными изменениями код будет выглядеть вот так:

```cs
switch (z)
{
    case < 0:
        F = Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y) * Math.Cos(y);
        break;
    case 0:
        F = Math.Log(x);
        break;
    case > 0:
        F = Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y);
        break;
}
```

Либо более современная конструкция, рекомендуется

```cs
F = z switch
{
    < 0 => Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y) * Math.Cos(y),
    0 => Math.Log(x),
    > 0 => Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y)
};
```

А если версия дотнета ниже, то обычный `if-else`

```cs
if (z < 0)
    F = Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y) * Math.Cos(y);
else if (z == 0)
    Math.Log(x);
else
    F = Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y);
```

Или даже тернарный оператор

```cs
F = z < 0 ? Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y) * Math.Cos(y) : z == 0 ? Math.Log(x) : Math.Sin(x) * Math.Sin(x) + Math.Cos(y);
```

Выглядит монструозно, но зато в одну строку.

Comment: Я бы отфоматировал условный оператор как-то так: https://pastebin.com/SFWT3uZE, чтобы было похоже на структуру if/elseif/else.

Comment: @VladD я хотел это сделать, но потом решил оставить как есть.